# How to set a tableview cell's border and color when selected

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code that sets sets a red border around a custom table view cell with white in the middle when it is selected.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
 self.nameLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 // Set selected background view
 UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
 backgroundView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
 backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
 self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;

 // Set the content view
 CGRect frame  = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+5, self.bounds.origin.y+5, self.bounds.size.width-10, self.bounds.size.height-10);
 UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 [self addSubview:myImageView];
 self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill ;
 self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView]; 
}
```

I want the opposite: how would you create a cell that has red with a white border / padding?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor]; 
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

try this in custom cell there is a method `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` use this to change the state of selected and deselect state for example

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   if(selected)
   {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth  = 5.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

  }
  else
  {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth  = 5.0f;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  }

  // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

and also set `customCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` for cell while creating the cell

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try doing just the opposite such as this

```
 UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
 backgroundView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
 backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
 self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;

 // Set the content view
 CGRect frame  = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+5, self.bounds.origin.y+5, self.bounds.size.width-10, self.bounds.size.height-10);
 UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
myImageView.backgroundcolor=[UIColor redColor];
 [self addSubview:myImageView];
 self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill ;
 self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
```